# Telling if a list is the size of 1 in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm pretty new to prolog and I'm trying to write a predicate such that I can tell if a list is the list of size one or not. Currently I have this:

```
one([H | T]) :- H \= [] ,T == [].
```

There is problems with this, at least my logic is that if the `H` is not empty and the tail has nothing, then it must be the case that there is something in the head and thus has a size of one. Else it does not.

Some insight on solving this problem would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your answer works! What is the problem with it? It is a bit more complicated than necessary, but it is also very declarative in nature and makes the meaning of your predicate rather clear. It's true, however, that @Sergey Dymchenko's answer is cleaner.

Comment: @aBathologist OP's answer doesn't always work. For example, [A] is a list of size 1, and `length([A], L).` will give 'L = 1', but OP's code fails on `one([A])`. The reason is that it fails on `one([[]]).` Correct code could be just `one([H | T]) :- T==[].`, but of course that's equal to `one([_])`.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko Thanks! I had overlooked `[[]]`.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy, just one fact:

```
one([_]).
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so simple.

Comment: There's an implicit assumption here that the `one/1` predicate will be called with an instantiated argument: `one(L)` also succeeds, instantiating `L` to `[_]`.

Comment: @PauloMoura - I don't think that it is an assumption. Prolog's execution model works this way.

Comment: The issue is not how Prolog's execution model works but if the predicate will be used as a *test*-only predicate. If you want to test for *valid* lists (of one item), you'll need to check first for an instantiated argument.

Comment: @PauloMoura - You do need to respond with a "@Enigmativity" for me to get a notification of your reply. Luckily I had the question still up. Nevertheless, I think the assumption is that it is to be used for testing of valid instantiated lists. It is perfectly fine to to use this for uninstantiated lists of values. Your assumption is backwards.

Comment: @Enigmativity Is `[_|_]` what you meant by "uninstantiated lists of values"? I.e. "lists of possibly uninstantiated values"? Or do you also include calls such as `one(A)`? Do you expect the `one/1` predicate to be used ** only** for testing or also for "creating" single item lists? I do agree that the bit of the OP that reads "write a predicate such that I can tell if a list is the list of size one" strongly suggests that the predicate will only be called with its argument instantiated. But that doesn't mean that we shouldn't alert the OP to the implicit assumptions on the `one([_])` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the built-in `length/2`:

```
is_list_of_length_one( Xs ) :- length(Xs,1).
```

Or you could simply say

```
is_list_of_length_one( Xs ) :- nonvar(Xs) , Xs = [_] .
```

Comment: They differ: `is_list_of_length_one(Xs)` succeeds for the first but fails for the second.